# How to set Chromedriver Print preferences?

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to add Chrome preferences to set "Microsoft Print to PDF" as default in print preview page.

I found this documentation from Chromw, but I don't know how to "translate" to VBA.

- https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=DefaultPrinterSelection
- https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/pref_names.cc

What I tried:

```vb
Chrome.SetPreference "printing.default_destination_selection_rules.namePattern", "Microsoft Print to PDF"
Chrome.SetPreference "printing.default_destination_selection_rules.idPattern", "Microsoft Print to PDF"
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are using VBA. So don't bother with that and set the Windows default printer with it. You can reset it to it's original value, if needed. The below codes works with the Windows Registry.

Functions:
fnSetWinDefaultPrinterToMsPrinterPDF > sets Microsoft Print to PDF as Windows default printer

fnSetXLActivePrinterToMsPrinterPDF > It is a Bonus: sets Microsoft Print to PDF as the XL active printer. Only for the current open session.

fnRestoreToOldPrinter > restores the 'old' printer before running these changes. **MUST** be called in the current XL open session.

```
Option Explicit

Public mvarOldPrinterSettings As Variant

Function fnSetWinDefaultPrinterToMsPrinterPDF()
    'sets the Windows default printer to "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    'apply to all Windows apps - current user.

    Dim WSHShell As Object
    Dim varMsPrinterPDF As Variant
    
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    'reading the default printer config data
    mvarOldPrinterSettings = WSHShell.regread("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device")
    'gathering MsPrinterPDF config data
    varMsPrinterPDF = WSHShell.regread("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices\Microsoft Print to PDF")
    'set MsPrinterPDF as Windows default printer
    WSHShell.regwrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device", "Microsoft Print to PDF," & varMsPrinterPDF, "REG_SZ"

End Function

Sub fnSetXLActivePrinterToMsPrinterPDF()
    'sets the Application.ActivePrinter to "Microsoft Print to PDF"
    'only apply to this XL App open session. The Windows Default Printer is not changed

    Dim WSHShell As Object
    Dim varResp As Variant
    Dim strON As String
    
    If InStr(UCase(Application.ActivePrinter), "MICROSOFT PRINT TO PDF") = 0 Then
        Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        varResp = WSHShell.regread("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices\Microsoft Print to PDF")
        strON = " " & Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " ")(UBound(Split(Application.ActivePrinter, " ")) - 1) & " "
        Application.ActivePrinter = "Microsoft Print to PDF" & strON & Split(varResp, ",")(1)
    End If
    
End Sub

Sub fnRestoreToOldPrinter()
    'restores the 'old' Printer settings
    'using mvarOldPrinterSettings values
    'applies to all Windows apps - current user
    
    Dim WSHShell As Object
    
    Set WSHShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WSHShell.regwrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows\Device", mvarOldPrinterSettings, "REG_SZ"

End Sub
```

If after all you want to reset the default printer to the one it was before, you have to run the `fnRestoreToOldPrinter` function, yet on the same XL session you run the other (the first one above)